# SectorMark position changes in ScrollView - SwiftUI Chart

Tags: swift, swiftui

When using a Pie Chart with the new SwiftUI `Chart` nested in a `ScrollView` the positions of the `SectorMark` changes when user scrolls, essentially the layout of the Chart changes.

This leads to a weird UX where the Chart information moves position if the user scrolls Y:Axix even by 1 pixel.

```
enum Gender: String {
    case male
    case female
    case notSet
}

extension Gender: Plottable {
    var primitivePlottable: String {
        rawValue
    }
}

struct Stats {
    let city: String
    let population: Int
    let gender: Gender
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let stats: [Stats]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView() {
            Chart {
                ForEach(stats, id: \.city) { stat in
                    SectorMark(
                        angle: .value("Gender", stat.population),
                        innerRadius: .ratio(0.618),
                        angularInset: 1.5
                    )
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                    .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Gender", stat.gender))
                }
            }
            .chartLegend(alignment: .center, spacing: 18)
            .scaledToFit()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: more typos in your code, your `BarMark` should be `SectorMark`, you are having us on again, after you deleted your previous question.